# Write files to disk in sorted order in bash

Tags: bash, filesystems

I'd like to reorder files on my usb stick. The problem is the mp3 reader which will read the files in the exact order as they were written to the stick.
The only way to output the order in which the player reads'em is to use **ls -f** which outputs the content unsorted.

It doesn't help to touch every file to update the last write time, I already tried that. It still remains in the same order if I output it with **ls -f**

I already thought about "rewriting" the FAT to correct the order but I thought maybe the community knows an easier way. Probably there is a way in bash to accomplish this.

[image: Output of ls -lf]

Comment: Filesystems do not, in general, guarantee that they will return files in the order in which they were created. In fact, filesystems with directory indexes usually _won't_ do this regardless.

Comment: use something other than FAT?

Comment: maybe my assumption was wrong, but the output of the unsorted directory content is the same as the player reads it. I need a way to change this unsorted state.

Comment: I'm using FAT - the player can't read anything else.

Comment: The caveat _was_ given with respect to filesystems in general, as opposed to FAT in particular.

Comment: Try Charles Duffy's answer - it will definitely work.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it's about user-level interaction with the operating system. It has been answered on [unix.se]: [Reorder folders on FAT32 drive](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59956/reorder-folders-on-fat32-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer is best summarized as "it's a fools' errand; don't try". Filesystems in general do not make guarantees about the order in which results are returned, and there's no guarantee that this order matches any canonical on-disk order. (Results may be returned from a cache; from an unordered index; etc).

If you insist on trying...

```
dest=$1
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -t tempdir.XXXXXX)
mv "$dest"/* "$tmpdir"    # move files out of the location
for f in "$tmpdir"/*; do  # globs are implicitly sorted in LC_COLLATE order
  mv "$f" "$dest/"        # ...so move them back in in that order.
done
```

Comment: Actually, this WILL work, and I did it several times already. Cheap MP3 players supporting FAT partitions up to 4GB act exactly, like OP described.

Comment: Depending on the FAT implementation you're using, this may not even work, unless you re-create the file system in between emptying it and putting stuff back. It depends on how freed clusters are added back to the free cluster chain. Depending on how that's done, you may find that the "first" file added back to an "empty" (but not newly-created) FAT file system does not necessarily go at the "front" of the disk...

Comment: There is one small error on the second line - it should be tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -t tempdir.XXXXXX)